# Home Graph API error "Requested entity was not found.",

Tags: google-home

am successfully able to sync my device in google home but when I try to send the `reportStateNotification` then am getting this error

```
"error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

can you tell me where am I wrong
I used the same `AgentId` that I sent for the sync request but the same error happening

when I try to link the smart home then after authorization google assistant sends the intent of sync and that intent goes to the `app.onSYnc()` I returning the doorbell data in the payload so where am getting wrong.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to register my agent in homegraph because this error is occuring because my device or agent is not registered on homegraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize a HomeGraph client to be able to access device states. You can find a detailed breakdown of how to do that in [Inspecting Home Graph](https://medium.com/google-developers/aog-protips-inspecting-home-graph-503df93b7a91).